# Membership contribution page won't load in Chrome browser

Tags: civimember

Lately our membership new/renewal form will not load in Chrome (in my case Windows ver 79.0.3945.88). But it has been working correctly in Chrome for several years. I don't know what's changed.

I have just tested that the membership form comes up okay in:

Firefox 71.0 (windows)

Windows Phone 8.1

Safari on iOS 13.

System: civicrm 5.15.1, WordPress 5.3.2

Edit with more info:

When the membership page loads okay, there are no warnings or errors in the civicrm log. But when the membership page stalls, there is the warning in the log:

Jan 06 17:25:33  [warning] CiviCRM thinks site is not SSL, redirecting to {url}
Array
(
    [url] => https://idahonativeplants.org/membership/
)

I think this is a good clue, and the problem only affects Chrome. The bug only appears when you go to the home page, then use the Membership menu item. If you first visit another contribution page on the site, then use the Membership menu the membership form comes up right away. Weird.

Comment: Check the javascript console for errors.

Comment: Didn't see any errors there. There was a warning about a url redirect, but that happens on a lot of pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by making the site's home page secure https. There seems to be a glitch when Chrome goes from an http page to https, at least on our site.

Comment: Yes you definitely need to get your canonical urls sorted so you are not switching. it could be that you have something out of synch in either your server settings or your civicrm.settings.php

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me on chrome Version 79.0.3945.88.

Imagine it's specific to your solution however I've only tested with 5.19, almost certainly something in the console like @Demerit suggested.

Should be aware that was a security release recently so make sure you have your solution secured too :).

Comment: I can reproduce the error with these steps:

1. go to https://idahonativeplants.org, 2. then use the 'Membership' menu item. Very often the page won't load, and I have gotten some user complaints on this.

Comment: The whole page? Went through the process and seems fine to me. Could potentially be related to Chrome issues on windows 7? I've seen a few issues regarding windows 7 and Chrome recently.

Comment: Okay, I had a bit more of a play with this after spamming it a bit I was able to get it to stall on page load? Page took 1.4 mins to load.  Jquery-ui took 1.3mins, however the connection 'stalled' so for me this could be server related? What is the hosting setup? Server response times seem high so would suggest looking at that :).

Comment: We are using shared Linux hosting with cPanel, Wordpress. The membership contribution page loads in the other browsers okay. There are 2 other contribution pages on the site, and if I visit them first with Chrome, they load okay, then go to the membership page and see that it now loads right away. So it's all pretty strange.

Comment: It's got the same bug in Edge on Windows 10, so I guess it could be a server problem. Or since Edge is Chromium based now, it's a browser engine problem.

Comment: It seemed intermittent to me, there must be a reason that file took 1.3 mins to be sent from your server.  Testing around the site and the server response time is slow so for me that's the first thing to look at along with any logs.